# Dart - Apply lottie animation over text

Tags: flutter, dart, lottie

I am trying to display a lottie confetti animation when a user enters a valid coupon code. I want the animation in front of the screen without taking any space of its own (like position absolute in CSS).

```
if (isApplyCouponSuccess)
                Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Lottie.asset(
                        'assets/images/confetti.json',
                        repeat: true,
                        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                        errorBuilder: (_, __, ___) {
                          return const SizedBox();
                        },
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        top: 150,
                        left: 0,
                        right: 0,
                        child:
                        Text(
                          couponMsg,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Theme
                              .of(context)
                              .primaryColor),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]
                ),
```

The above code gives the following result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `Positioned` widget to position the Lottie animation wherever you want.

```dart
Positioned(
  top: 100, <-- Change these values to your likings
   // alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Lottie.asset(
               'assets/images/confetti.json',
                repeat: true,
                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                errorBuilder: (_, __, ___) {
                return const SizedBox();
               },
             ),
           ),
```

You need to wrap main widget inside, in the example, it's `Column` and with `Positioned` widget you move lottie file anywhere on the screen and even control width and height of the file.

```dart
class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  const Example({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter app'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Text('Hello world!'),
                Text('Hello world!'),
                Text('Hello world!'),
                Text('Hello world!'),
                Text('Hello world!'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            // top: 100,
            // alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Lottie.asset(
              'assets/confetti.json',
              repeat: true,
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              errorBuilder: (_, __, ___) {
                return const SizedBox();
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Result
[image]

Comment: Hi, it's not showing anything now: https://i.imgur.com/mUQJX9B.png

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that you are using stack widget only on a text. You have to use stack widget on top of cart widget, so you can control the area of Lottie file anywhere on the whole cart

Comment: No, it's still the same.

Comment: I updated my code and the result again. Could you please check it?

Comment: I meant to say that you have to wrap the very first widget (for example its name is `Cart`) with `Stack. Let me add an example to the answer.

Comment: No, it doesn't work since I am using SingleChildScrollView. I get this error "Unhandled Exception: Cannot hit test a render box with no size. "